# Cannot delete in_memory workspace

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.3, delete, in-memory, error-000725

I wanted to use in_memory workspace, however I can't clear it. No matter if I use in Python window, in ArcMap this:

```
arcpy.Buffer_analysis("something", "in_memory/buffer", 399)
arcpy.Delete_management("in_memory")
arcpy.Buffer_analysis("something", "in_memory/buffer", 3345)
```

or this:

```
arcpy.Buffer_analysis("something", "in_memory/buffer", 399)
arcpy.Delete_management("in_memory/buffer")
arcpy.Buffer_analysis("something", "in_memory/buffer", 3345)
```

I get the following error:

```
ExecuteError: ERROR 000725: Output Feature Class: Dataset in_memory\buffer already exists.
```

In_memory gets normally cleared when I restart ArcMap. 
How can I clear in_memory?

EDIT:

Output from answer proposed by KHibma:

```
>>> arcpy.CopyFeatures_management("linie", "in_memory/foo1")
<Result 'in_memory\\foo1'>
>>> arcpy.Exists("in_memory/foo1")
True
>>> arcpy.Delete_management("in_memory")
<Result 'true'>
>>> arcpy.Exists("in_memory/foo1")
True
>>> arcpy.Delete_management("in_memory/foo1")
<Result 'true'>
>>> arcpy.Exists("in_memory/foo1")
True
```

So it seems that neither of deleting from in_memory methods is working at all.

Comment: What version of ArcGIS are you running this in?  Maybe instead of deleting the object just overwrite it using arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True

Comment: I am using 10.3. Overwriting would be only temporary solution. I'd rather have fully functional environment.

Comment: @Kubson Can you please expand on what you mean by "I'd rather have fully functional environment"?  In what way does `arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True` not work?

Comment: @Midavalo For example, if I would like to release memory to perform some further actions (some next loop using previously created objects?)

Comment: @Kubson Please [edit] your question in response to any comments rather than adding as additional comment.

Answer (score 2):

The workflow you describe works as expected for me in the Python window. Perhaps copy/paste all of the python window session into your question, showing the result of each operation.

In short, yes, you can delete items out of the in_memory workspace.

```
>>> arcpy.CopyFeatures_management(r"Exterior Editing\Trees", "in_memory/foo1")
<Result 'in_memory\\foo1'>
>>> arcpy.Exists("in_memory/foo1")
True
>>> arcpy.Delete_management("in_memory")
<Result 'true'>
>>> arcpy.Exists("in_memory/foo1")
False
>>> arcpy.CopyFeatures_management(r"Exterior Editing\Trees", "in_memory/foo1")
<Result 'in_memory\\foo1'>
>>> arcpy.Exists("in_memory/foo1")
True
>>> arcpy.Delete_management("in_memory/foo1")
<Result 'true'>
>>> arcpy.Exists("in_memory/foo1")
False
```